# Simple Application To Transfer File From Localhost To SFTP

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm looking to create a simple desktop application that transfers a file from my local machine to an SFTP location.

I have attempted the below, which transfers a file from my local machine to another location on my machine.. But struggling on how to transfer to an SFTP location, which uses a username and password.

```
namespace SFTPTranfer
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileToCopy = "C:\\TransferFileTest.txt";
            string newLocation = "C:\\copiedFiles\\copiedTransferFileTest.txt";
            //string newLocation = "https:\\URL\folder1\folder2";
            //string URLUser = "Test";
            //string URLPassword = "Password";
            string folderLocation = "C:\\copiedFiles";

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderLocation))
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileToCopy))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(fileToCopy, newLocation, true);
                    Console.WriteLine("File copied.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No such file.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No such directory.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Any help appreciated

*UPDATE*

Decided to use this approach: http://blog.deltacode.be/2012/01/05/uploading-a-file-using-sftp-in-c-sharp/

Works fine.

Comment: Your new approach is exactly what I proposed ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [SSH.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/). Here's the simple example:

```
using(var fileStream = new FileStream(fileToCopy, FileMode.Open))
using(var client = new SftpClient(host, port, login, password))
{
    client.Connect();
    client.UploadFile(fileStream, "/path/on/server");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a FtpWebRequest like:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
fileInfo = new FileInfo("FILEPATH");
request.ContentLength = fileInfo.Length;
FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
while (totalBytes > 0)
{
   int bytes = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
   requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
   totalBytes = totalBytes - bytes;
}
fileStream.Close();
requestStream.Close();
FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string value = uploadResponse.StatusDescription;
uploadResponse.Close();
```

This works for me for a FTP-Connection. Not sure if it works for SFTP. But it should work

**Edit**
You have to set

```
request.EnableSsl = true;
```

Than it should work for SFTP

Comment: No, this doesn't work for an SFTP connection. SFTP is different than FTP. An SFTP connection can not be created with the inbuilt .NET classes.

Comment: @Tomtom - Thanks for the above. I copied the above into my solution, i am getting errors over fileInfo, totalBytes and buffer - "The name fileinfo does not exist in the current context"... Do i need to include a library? Also, where do i place request.EnableSsl = true; ?? Thanks

Comment: You need to reference System.IO; The EnableSSL you can put somewhere before request.GetRespons.